# names repeated in dropdown.(sql query )

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
  SELECT ID,Name FROM Master

    id  Name
    1   John
    2   John
    3   Jack
    4   Max
    5   Jack
    6   Max
    7   Max
```

using above query i get all names repeated in dropdown.
    i have to bind data in dropdown foreach Name there have
    respective ID How can i do that.

Comment: Do you want `Name + ID`  to appear in your dropdown ?

Comment: I USE THIS QUERY SELECT DISTINCT ID,Name FROM Master but getting repeated data

Comment: If your users select `John` what id (`1` or `2`) do you expect to be bound?  There are two possible answers which is why you are getting repeated data

Comment: How do you want the output? What text is to be shown in the dropdown and what value do you want each entry in the dropdown to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the logic behind the data, but to get one name only once you have to filter out duplicate names and settle for one of the ids from the duplicate names.

```
SELECT MIN(id), Name 
FROM Master
GROUP BY Name
```

The query above will output the occurence with the lowest id for each name, given that the id column is numeric.

The reason that your distinct query does not work, is that distinct filters on all columns in the result set, so in this case both name and id are used for uniqueness.

If you for some reason need all the ids for each name you have to filter on the ASP.NET side or look up the ids in the database once you know which person was selected.

Answer (score -1):

Only place the Name column you will get the unique output. I think the problem is that the distinct keyword checks the primary key which is different per each row so it returns all the columns you only have to place the Name column. ( my understanding about distinct )

```
SELECT distinct Name FROM Master

output
Jack
John
Max

-- Below is what i tested
-- Created a table
Create table mytable(
ID bigint identity primary key,
UserName varchar(50)
)
-- Insert the records

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(UserName) VALUES('John')
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(UserName) VALUES('John')
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(UserName) VALUES('Jack')
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(UserName) VALUES('Max')
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(UserName) VALUES('Jack')
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable(UserName) VALUES('John')

-- If i use below query
select distinct * from mytable
ID  UserName
1   John
2   John
3   Jack
4   Max
5   Jack
6   John

 -- and if i use this
select distinct UserName from mytable

output
Jack
John
Max

-- I think you should not allow the user to enter multiple users with the same name   

-- what do you think about this
 select  UserName +' '+CAST(ID as varchar) as [Users] from mytable
John 1
John 2
Jack 3
Max 4
Jack 5
John 6
 -- IN your code you can create a list<string,int> and stored in it. you can easily manage it in code
```

Comment: I USE THIS QUERY SELECT DISTINCT ID,Name FROM Master but getting repeated data..i want query not code man

Comment: you db name is Master ???  master db already presents in sql server how it allows you to create another db with same name.

Comment: i have to search using id not name

Comment: why you are allowing multiple Names ? you can easily remove the repeated items in your code

Comment: @lax what do you think about this
 select  UserName +' '+CAST(ID as varchar) as [Users] from mytable it will return Name concatenated with their ID

Answer (score -1):

Try this query it will return grouped as one

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID), Name FROM your_tbl Group BY Name
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is a MySQL function. The OP is using Sql Server.

Comment: FYI GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.